# Punctuation characters appearing incorrectly in front of a string

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have an event that is handled by changing a label's text but punctuation characters keep incorrectly appearing at the beginning of the output. I am using C# in Visual Studio 2010.

C#: `KeyPressLabel.Text = "Some text,,";`

Output: `,,Some text`

This only happens when the last characters in the string is punctuation.

Comment: is the label right-to-left?

Comment: Yes it was set right to left. I think I accidentally set the form's property and it got inherited by default. I feel silly now. Thanks for resolving that :)

Comment: np. I recognized it b/c I was working with something similar just yesterday. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set the label's property `RightToLeft` with the value `No` in order to get my desired output. According to the tool tip, RightToLeft "Indicates whether the component should draw right-to-left for RTL languages."

My thanks to Drew for providing the answer.